# How can I expose all properties in an entity using @Expose decorator from class-transformer?

Tags: node.js, typescript, class-transformer

I used the class-transformer library in my project implemented on NodeJS, but I did not find a way to expose all the properties of my  entity.
I tried using the `@Expose()` decorator at class level, but it does not work.
I hope to find a solution because it's a little exhausting to use the expose decorator on each property in the class.

Example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```js
  @Expose() // Expose all properties
  export class User {
     name: string;
     phone: string;
     age: number
  };
```

Currently it only works if I define expose on every property:

```js
  export class User {
    @Expose() name: string;
    @Expose() phone: string;
    @Expose() age: number
  };
```